# Finding data where the value is the same in two columns from the same table

Tags: sql, hive, hql

So I have a simple table that holds items we offered to a customer and the items the user actually used, per day.

```
date         |  offered_name  |  used_name  |  h_id
----------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-20   | Obsidian       |  Obsidian   |  100
2019-06-20   | Obsidian       |  Limestone  |  101
2019-06-20   | Limestone      |  Sandstone  |  102
2019-06-21   | Obsidian       |  Limestone  |  100
2019-06-21   | Obsidian       |  Sandtone   |  101
2019-06-21   | Limestone      |  Limestone  |  102
```

I want to find all the instances where the offered item matches the used item. The user can change their used_item, so I only care if they have ever matched the offered_name at least once. If they have never matched then I don’t want to select them. Output for the above would look like:

```
h_id  | used_offered_item_at_least_once
---------------------------------------
100   | 1 
101   | 0 
102   | 1
```

Similar to this question [SQL - find all instances where two columns are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726186/sql-find-all-instances-where-two-columns-are-the-same) but I want to compare two different columns rather than checking just the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation`

```
select h_id,
       cast(sign(sum(case when offered_name = used_name then 
          1 
       else
          0
       end)) as int) as used_offered_item_at_least_once
  from tab
 group by h_id
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Never used a conditional aggregation before, thanks! As an aside, how would I only select where `used_offered_item_at_least_once` = 1? Putting it into a where clause as usual doesn't seem to work

Comment: After putting your solution into a subquery, I was then able to use `used_offered_item_at_least_once` in my `where` clause. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I would write this using a `case` expression:

```
select id,
       max(case when offered_name = used_name then 1 else 0 end) as used_offered_item_at_least_once
from t
group by id;
```

I cannot think of a simpler way to express the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and having:

```
select h_id, count(1) "used_offered_item_at_least_once" from your_table
where offered_name  = used_name
group by h_id
having count(1) = 1
```

Comment: having count(1) = 1 returns the only once matched users.